# Find a valid english phrase that is identical to what the user entered, save a missing consonant

Tags: performance, strings, file, rust

The Task:

> The user enters a path to a dictionary file (one word per line) and a phrase as system arguments. My code must then find phrases containing only valid English words, generated by removing one consonant from the user's phrase.

I wrote this as part of an effort to learn Rust, the task is copied from a piece of homework that I had to answer in Java. As such I have written a solution in both Java and Rust, however I was under the impression that Rust was generally faster than Java, but my Java code is significantly quicker. Being new to Rust I don't know what is slowing down my code.

```
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() == 3 {
        let dict_path = &args[1];
        let mut phrase = args[2].clone();

        let dict_file = File::open(dict_path).expect("Failed to open file");
        let br = BufReader::new(dict_file);
        let dict: Vec<String> = br.lines().map(|l| l.unwrap()
                                                    .to_string()
                                                    .to_lowercase())
                                          .collect();

        let mut num_alter = 0;
        for (i, ch) in phrase.clone().chars().enumerate() {
            if is_consonant(&ch) {
                phrase.remove(i);
                num_alter += print_if_word(&phrase, &dict);
                phrase.insert(i, ch);
            }
        }

        println!("Number of alternatives: {}", num_alter);

    }
}

fn print_if_word(phrase: &String, dict: &Vec<String>) -> u8 {
    let words: Vec<&str> = phrase.split(" ").collect();
    let all_words_match = words.iter().all(|w| dict.contains(&w.to_string().to_lowercase()));
    if all_words_match {println!("{}", phrase); 1} else {0}
}

fn is_consonant(ch: &char) -> bool {
    let consonants = vec!['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    ch.is_alphabetic() && !consonants.contains(ch)
}
```

Java Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class LostConsonants {
    private static HashSet<String> dict = new HashSet<>();
    private static final HashSet<Character> CONSONANTS = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('q', 'w', 'r', 't', 'y', 'p', 's', 'd',
                                                              'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b',
                                                              'n', 'm', 'Q', 'W', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'P', 'S', 'D', 'F',
                                                              'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M'
                                                              ));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.out.printf("Expected 2 command line arguments, but got %d.\n", args.length);
        System.out.println("Please provide the path to the dictionary file as the first argument and a sentence as the second argument.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String dictPath = args[0];
    String phrase = args[1];
    vaildWords(dictPath);
    int num = 0;

    StringBuilder phraseBuilder = new StringBuilder(phrase);

    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
        Character curr = phraseBuilder.charAt(i);
        if (CONSONANTS.contains(curr)) {
            phraseBuilder.deleteCharAt(i);
            num += printIfWord(phraseBuilder);
            phraseBuilder.insert(i, curr);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(num > 0 ? "Found " + num + " alternatives." : "Could not find any alternatives.");

}

static int printIfWord(StringBuilder phrase) {
    String[] words = phrase.toString()
            .replace("[.,]", "")
            .toLowerCase()
            .split(" ");
    if (Stream.of(words).allMatch(dict::contains)) {
        System.out.println(phrase);
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

static void vaildWords(String dictPath) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dictPath))) {
        reader.lines().map(String::toLowerCase).forEach(dict::add);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.printf("File not found: %s (No such file or directory)\n", dictPath);
        System.out.println("Invalid dictionary, aborting.");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: while knowing nothing about rust, I will say that `is_consonant` looks inefficient.  Use a hash type rather than an array, and store the list of consonants to avoid a call to `is_alphabetic`.  Define `consonants` such that it's only initialized once, not on every call.   Also make sure that `phrase.remove` + `phrase.insert` is faster than moving `phrase.clone` inside the loop (and discarding the modified phrase).

Comment: I'd say the biggest thing I see is that dict should be a HashSet. Seeing the Java code would make it easier to compare, so we know what to critique regarding the algorithm itself vs how it was translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of comparing the two implementations, I only see two differences.

Your Java code uses a HashSet for dict while your Rust code uses a Vec. Since the desired use of dict is simply lookups, a HashSet is indeed the best data structure to use. This change is very easy to make, mostly since `collect` is a generic method. You can simply change the type of `dict` to `HashSet<String>` and the words will be collected into a hashset. This should result in a very large improvement, assuming your dictionary is sufficiently large.

The other difference is with `is_consonsant`. I don't see this change being very significant. I think the way you're doing it in the Rust implementation *may* actually be faster, especially if you use `is_ascii_alphabetic` instead. My reasoning for this is that a linear search through an array is typically faster than a hashset when the number of elements is very small. An array-based static lookup table would probably be best anyways. Overall though, this optimization is likely insignificant and only if you need this boost, you should benchmark different approaches.

Here's how I might write this program, with some comments for explanation. (Note: I compiled this but didn't actually test it.) If you have any questions about why I do something a certain way, feel free to ask.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io::BufReader;

pub fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() != 3 {
        // eprintln prints to stderr
        eprintln!("Expected 2 command line arguments, but got {}.", args.len() - 1);
        eprintln!("Please provide the path to the dictionary file as the first argument and a sentence as the second argument.");
        return;
    }

    let dict_path = &args[1];
    let phrase = &args[2];

    let dict_file = File::open(dict_path).expect("Failed to open file");
    // You can collect into a hashset
    let dict: HashSet<String> = BufReader::new(dict_file)
        .lines()
        .map(|l| l.unwrap().to_string().to_lowercase())
        .collect();

    let mut num_alter = 0;
    let mut phrase_alter = phrase.to_string();
    for (i, ch) in phrase.chars().enumerate() {
        if is_consonant(ch) {
            phrase_alter.remove(i);
            num_alter += print_if_word(&phrase, &dict);
            phrase_alter.insert(i, ch);
        }
    }

    println!("Number of alternatives: {}", num_alter);
}

// &str is almost always prefered over &String
fn print_if_word(phrase: &str, dict: &HashSet<String>) -> u8 {
    // No need to collect to a vector, just chain iterator methods.
    let all_words_match = phrase
        .split_whitespace()
        .all(|w| dict.contains(&w.to_string().to_lowercase()));
    if all_words_match {
        println!("{}", phrase);
        1
    } else {
        0
    }
}

// prefer taking by value instead of reference whenever the type is Copy and reasonably small
fn is_consonant(ch: char) -> bool {
    // Since your Java code only allowed ascii consonants, I will do the same here.
    if !ch.is_ascii() {
        return false;
    }

    // Fastest solution is most likely a static lookup table like
    // static CONSONANT: [bool; 256] = [false, false, ...];
    // However, the solution below is reasonably fast and is likely
    // dwarfed by other costs in the program.

    let b = (ch as u8).to_ascii_lowercase();

    b.is_ascii_lowercase()
        && match b {
            b'a' | b'e' | b'i' | b'o' | b'u' => false,
            _ => true,
        }
}
```